# Sharing data between partials

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've become a little lost trying to figure out the correct way to share some data between some partials. I'll do my best to explain the setup:

**Layouts**

`_Layout.cshtml` - this is the main layout for the site: top navigation, footer etc.

`_SectionLayout.cshtml` - this is a sub-layout of _Layout.cshtml and makes the main content area of the site into a header and two lower columns - the left column is a menu, the right loads various page content

**Partials**

`_SectionMenu.cshtml` - this is the mark-up for the left hand column menu, it builds the menu based on an ViewModel that it expects to be passed which contains an enumerable list of menu items

`_SectionHeader.cshtml` - this is the mark-up for the section header, it builds the header similarly to the menu above

All of the above are located in the `Shared` folder.

A series of controllers use the _SectionLayout style to have a consistent style for areas of the site with related pages. The layout is specified on these controllers via a `_ViewStart.cshtml` within the `Views` folder for each controller. Each controller implements an `ActionResult` method for both `_SectionMenu()` and `_SectionHeader()`, returning appropriately populated ViewModels for the section.

The individual pages that the menu loads have been setup to do something along the lines of the following:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView();
else
    return View();
```

So that they can be loaded either directly via a standard GET request (which loads the header, menu and layout), or as a partial to be inserted into the right hand column of the layout. Now this is all seems to work well, until I come to deciding how to load data that is shared between actions and partials within the same controller while trying to adhere to DRY where I can and cut down on code re-use. The problem is as follows:

Within a typical controller of this type, a single full load of the page will invoke three `ActionResult` methods: `_SectionHeader()`, `_SectionMenu()` and whatever the main action was. Often, all three of them need to access data from the same, or similar database queries. For example, a `ProductController` may have an `Index` action which shows an overview of the product information. The header will need to show the name of the product, the menu will show statistics such as the number of images. All of this data comes from a single query which returns all of the product information from the database, but how am I best able to share this data between the three actions? Some ideas I've had:

- Make all the ViewModels inherit from a base view model for that controller and pass it through to the partials after opening it in the main action
- Store the data in the `ViewBag` or `ViewData`
- Just open the database multiple times and hope that my ORM is clever enough to realise it doesn't need to fetch it from the server multiple times within the same request

The first one seems to me to be rather complicated for what is a fairly simple ask. The second always feels like a cheap easy way out and I try to avoid it. The third, I'm not confident enough that what I'm using (Dapper) will know not to go to the server again for the same query.

To make things just a little more complex, some of the Actions for a controller may not need to load the main database query. To extend the example from above, the Images option in the menu of the Product controller may need to run an additional query to load the list of associated images, but if it is being requested as an ajax call, it really doesn't need to load the main query for the header and menu sections.

I'm comfortable with the logic for that, but does every one of the actions within a controller of this type need to look something like the following, or can DRY be leveraged here?

```
public ActionResult Images(int? id)
{
    if (!CheckExists(id))
        return HttpNotFound();

    // if this is an action that doesn't normally need the shared data,
    // only load it if it isn't an ajax request, as then the menu/header will require it
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        LoadSharedData(); // part of the question is how I handle this part

    // load the particular model for this page
    var model = GetImagesModel();

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView(model);
    else
        return View(model);
}
```

In a section with say 10 similar actions in it, seeing all that extremely similar code repeated tells me that I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance for any help. If I haven't explained something well, please ask and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: It's not cheap. ViewData was built for that purpose.

Comment: It's not type safe though, at least not without casting the `ViewData` or `ViewBag` data. It would still leave a lot of repeated code in my actions too. I can accept it if that's really the only, or the best way, but it feels like I could make some better architectural decisions to simplify what I'm doing. The various ways that you can fit together layouts, partials and viewmodels leave a lot of scope for how you build systems like this and I just wonder if I'm missing a trick?

Comment: If that's the case, you could create a custom class that manage all the property inside ViewData, and always have that custom class to be stored in ViewData. By doing that, it would prevent a lot of things and make ViewData easier to be maintained

Comment: I would still need to cast my class out of the `ViewData` though? And I would still have to perform identical checking and data loading code in all of the actions within the controller - nearly all of my `ActionResult` methods would need to look something like the method at the end of my original question?

Comment: I just tried it out using the `ViewBag` and it doesn't actually work. I set breakpoints on the code and watched the data be set correctly, but when the controller for the partial executed the `ViewBag` was empty again. I'm using `@Html.Action()` to render the partial - I need to do this so that it can actually have a controller behind it. I suppose that makes it not a partial at all, really, but rather just a reusable action that is used like a partial. I'm still having difficulty seeing how I can share the same data between the main action and the partial actions though!

Comment: How if you used @Html.Partial() instead?

Comment: Then the controller for the partial never fires. As I understand it partials are rendered directly with whatever you pass to them as their model, not via a controller action.

Comment: Understood. Another wild suggestion is to put whatever data you required in the main view in the hiddenfield. You can serialize the data as JSON in that hiddenfield. Then, in the relevant partialView, you can bind the data into the view itself. This approach is good if you are using MVVM like knockoutJS.